# Rider changes editorconfig

Tags: macos, .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider, editorconfig

I'm using Rider for a .net-core project I'm working on, and I have an `.editorconfig` file at the root level. I've set up the preferences in Rider to look like this:

[image]

For some reason Rider will change the `.editorconfig` file without warning or notification. This setting in the screenshot makes it seem like `.editorconfig` will override Rider, but for some reason Rider changes it.

Comment: What exactly is changed in `.editorconfig`?

Comment: Whoops haha sorry. The line ending is changed from `end_of_line = lf` to `end_of_line = crlf`

Comment: @nickn, could you please create a new support request via the menu (Help | Contact Support) and attach the following information to it:

♦ your Rider version
♦ your initial and the final (changed) .editorconfig file
♦ a zipped Rider config folder (Help | Browse Special Paths... -> Config directory)